# Spark Issue with Dataframe.collectAsList method when ran on Multi-node Spark Cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a list from a spark dataframe using collectAsList method and reading the columns by iterating through the rows. The spark java job runs on a multi-node cluster, where the config is set to spawn multiple executors. Please suggest some alternative method to do the below functionality in JAVA.

```
        List<Row> list = df.collectAsList();
        List<Row> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Row r: list) {
           String colVal1 = r.getAs(colName1);
           String colVal2 = r.getAs(colName2);
           String[] nestedValues = new String[allCols.length];
           nestedValues[0]=colVal1 ;
           nestedValues[1]=colVal2 ;
           .
           .
           .
           responseList.add(RowFactory.create(nestedValues));

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question as written is hard to answer because it is very generic.  What problem are you having that you want help with?  How much data are you trying to process?  From what you have in your question "The spark java job runs on a multi-node cluster, where the config is set to spawn multiple executors" . That is fine, the main advantage of Spark is to run on multiple executors on multiple nodes.

Comment: If there's only one row in the dataframe, there's nothing necessarily wrong here. What kind of processing are you doing? Why not make the Row an actual useful Java object related to your use cases?

Comment: i have updated my question to provide more details on what exactly i am trying to do. Could you please suggest some alternative in JAVA w.r.t. the same functionality i am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The benefit of Spark is that you can process a large amount of data using the memory and processors across multiple executors on multiple nodes.  The problem you are having might be due to using `collectAsList` and then processing the data.  `collectAsList` brings all the data into the "driver" which is a single JVM on a single node.  It should be used as a final step, to gather results after you have processed data.  If you are trying to bring a very large amount of data into the driver and then process it, it could be very slow or fail and you are not actually using Spark to process your data at that point.  Instead of using `collectAsList` use the methods available on the `DataFrame` to do the processing the data, such as `map()`

Definitions of driver and executor https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

In the Java API a DataFrame is a DataSet . Here's the DataSet documentation.  Use the methods here to process your data https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i need an alternative method to do the same processing as above. Please suggest

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help with an alternative method when I don't know what you are trying to do.  Any more context you can provide about what you are doing might help me give a more specific answer.

Comment: I am looping over a dataframe and reading each rows, parsing few columns, transforming them and creating another dataframe. So i am using the collectAsList method to loop through each row

Comment: i have updated my question to provide more details on what exactly i am trying to do. Could you please suggest some alternative in JAVA w.r.t. the same functionality i am trying to do.

Comment: FYI, I created a new answer with a specific suggestion based on your update.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I used the toLocalIterator() method for holding less data, this method will return the Iterator object. collectAsList() this method will return total data as List, but Iterator will directly fetch data from the driver while reading.
Code Like :

```
 Iterator<Row> itr = df.toLocalIterator();

       while(itr.hasNext()){

               Row row = itr.next();
               //do somthing

       }
```

Comment: Will this method read the entire data from all the executors or will it miss reading any data in any case?

Comment: it won't miss anything but performance is slow compared to the ForEach.

Comment: Ranjith, i have updated my question to provide more details on what exactly i am trying to do. Please suggest w.r.t. the same functionality i am trying to do, in JAVA as i am not used to Scala

Comment: Use normal for loop, it will gives better performance compared to For each in java.                                    Please read this article once: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/performance-comparison-of-different-for-loops-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

@Tony is on the spot. Here are few more points-
Big data needs to be scalable so that with more processing power more data can be processed in same time. This is achieved with parallel processing using multiple executers.

Spark is also resilience, if some executors die then it can recover easily.

Using collect() makes your processing heavily dependent on only 1 process/node which is driver. It won’t scale and more prone to failure.

Essentially you can use all Spark APIs except few of these - collect, collectAsList, show in production grade code. You can use them for testing as well as for small amount of data. You should't use them for large amount of data.

In your case you can simply do something like -

```
    Dataset<Row> df = // create your dataframe from a source like file, table etc.

    df.select("column1","column2",array("column1","column2").as("column3")).save(.... file name ..)
```

You can use tons for column based functions available on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html. These functions are pretty much everything you need, if not you can always read data into scala/java/python and operate on them using that language's syntax.

Comment: @user1326784 I have updated my answer on what you can use.

Comment: Salim, i have updated my question to provide more details on what exactly i am trying to do. Please suggest w.r.t. the same functionality i am trying to do, in JAVA as i am not used to Scala

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new answer to address the new specifics in your question.

Call `.map` on the dataframe, and put logic in a lambda to convert one row to a new row.

```
// Do your data manipulation in a call to `.map`,
// which will return another DataFrame.
DataFrame df2 = df.map(
  // This work will be spread out across all your nodes,
  // which is the real power of Spark.
    r -> {
      // I'm assuming the code you put in the question works,
      // and just copying it here.
      // Note the type parameter of <String> with .getAs
      String colVal1 = r.getAs<String>(colName1);
      String colVal2 = r.getAs<String>(colName2);
      String[] nestedValues = new String[allCols.length];
      nestedValues[0]=colVal1;
      nestedValues[1]=colVal2;
      .
      .
      .
      // Return a single Row
      RowFactory.create(nestedValues);
    }
);

// When you are done, get local results as Rows.
List<Row> localResultRows = df2.collectAsList();
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html